# No output while spoling to csv using sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been tasked with exporting the result of join of two tables for Jan, Feb, Mar 2019 from two databases. The output contains millions of records. I am therefore trying to spool the data for each day. However, after I run the spool script, there is no output written to the file. The task completes in few seconds. Last night, I was able to spool the data for 1 day. But since today morning, there is no output. Below is the script for the same. Also, If I try to run the select query within the brackets, I get a snapshot error. But if I query the tables individually in their respective databases, I am able to see results.

```
SET FEEDBACK off;
SET  HEADING on;
SET UNDERLINE off;
SET COLSEP ',';
spool C:\workspace\20190508\audit1.csv;
select /*csv*/
 a.msisdn,
 a.subs_score_01 segment, 
 b.text, b.campaign_code, b.channel
from
  (Select msisdn , text , campaign_code , channel from CAMPAIGN.UT_OUTBOUND_TARGET_HISTORY@INTERACT.CAMP_TO_INT_STANDBY
   where record_type = 'NOTIFICAT' and contact_date>= '01-Feb-2019'     and contact_date < '02-Feb-2019') b
INNER JOIN
intpro.NBA_SUBS_MODEL_CAR_T1 a
on b.msisdn = a.msisdn;
 spool off ;
```

Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: “spool path” seams to be invalid Oracle code? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESBTR/maxl_commands_spool.html It seams it has to be “spool on to ‘path’”

Comment: @RaymondNijland [`SPOOL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm) is a valid SQL*Plus command (and therefore, presumably, valid in SQL Developer), which accepts the filename as one of its parameters.

Comment: @Yuvraj is your contact_date column of DATE (or TIMESTAMP) datatype? If so, then you need to use `to_date` (or `to_timestamp`) to convert your date-as-a-string into a date, e.g. `contact_date >= to_date('01/02/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`

Comment: “SPOOL is a valid SQL*Plus command “ @Boneist when i read your link it said “SPOOL is not available in iSQL*Plus.“  wierd well you might be right i didnt work with Oracle for some while now

Comment: @RaymondNijland `iSQL*Plus` is a web version of SQL*Plus running on the database server, so it's perhaps not a surprise that it wouldn't support the spool command. Also, it's no longer shipped with the database since 11g, so bringing up iSQL*Plus is irrelevant these days.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - in spite of what the doc you cited says, the 'spool' syntax used by the OP is correct.  I'd say that is a documentation bug.  Hard to show as a comment here, but I just tried the 'spool on to filename' and got an error, where the usual 'spool filename' has worked for me for over 20 years.

Comment: Ok like i said i didnt work with Oracle for some time now and could not remember a time where i used the spool and or how i used it.. it is just bad its syntax is wrong in the documentation i think we all can agree on that one @EdStevens

Comment: What do you mean, you "get a snapshot error" when you run this query? What error is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved after I created a function and then calling the same in the select query.

```
Select /* csv */ msisdn , text , campaign_code , channel,get_score(msisdn) segment
from CAMPAIGN.UT_OUTBOUND_TARGET_HISTORY
where record_type = 'NOTIFICAT' and contact_date>= '02-Feb-2019' and contact_date < '03-Feb-2019';
```